# Pyinstaller Splashscreen: root.iconbitmap resets to default

Tags: python, tkinter, icons, pyinstaller, splash-screen

**Question:**
Is there a simple way setting:
`root.iconbitmap(default='Settings/ICON small.ico')`
for all tkinter windows while using (pyinstaller) splash screen? Pyinstaller --splash screen seems to reset iconbitmap to default "feather".

**Method:** Created a python application with Python Tkinter. Here I set the icon in window title for every tkinter root and toplevels with:

```
root.iconbitmap(default='Settings/ICON small.ico')
```

All functions perfect also after creating executable with: auto-py-to-exe. Also title bar icon for simpledialog is set:

```
simpledialog.askstring
```

Though after creating splashscreen in auto-py-to-exe the default set window Icon is reset, only the standard "feather" symbol is displayed.

**My investigation:**
Reset to standard feather icon likely caused by `pyi_splash`. Reset only occurs after creating executable. Searching internet: likely involved: tcl/tk but this is outside my skill level.

> **Edit:** Noticed that "One file" functions, iconbitmap can be set correctly. Only when using "One Dir" iconbitmap is set to default unwanted "feather".

```
try:
    import pyi_splash
    pyi_splash.update_text('Datacombiner Loaded ...')
    pyi_splash.close()
except:
    pass
```

Played around with abs. path (after searching internet) but trial and error method is inefficient (creating executable every time).

**Workarround:**
Here I set the icon with code below (for root and top levels) though inefficient reusing same line everytime:

```
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='Settings/ICON small.png'))
```

This solution does not work perfect. Title bar icon's for

```
simpledialog.askstring
```

Cannot be set. Small discomfort but sore in the eye. Looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here follows a summary/answer from observation by doing more tests. Maybe/hopefully someone else has more information why or how they occur.

All Examples below are including a splashscreen with Pyinstaller (auto-py-to-exe).

> **Problem:** When creating a "one dir" application with Pyinstaller (auto-py-to-exe) the default window icon for root and all toplevels (and `simpledialog.askstring`) *cannot* be set with `root.iconbitmap(default=path)`.

> **Workaround:** When working with "one dir" Pyinstaller only window icons with methods as: `root.tk.call('wm', ...)` are possible. Some window icons *cannot* be set like: `simpledialog.askstring`.

> **Compromis:** When creation a "one file" with Pyinstaller `root.iconbitmap(default=path)` is called correctly and all window icons are set *correctly* including:  `simpledialog.askstring`.